# Flag dates occurring after an event within individuals

Tags: sql, date, timestamp

I have a set of data in long format (several rows per person, person = id) where an event (event = 1) should only occur once. When the event has occurred, there should be no more data from that person.

I want to create a query with a new variable called flag (flag = 1) if any record appears after the event has taken place.

For example, id 5 is flagged below because a row of data appears after the event for that person. All other scenarios are OK.

So I need to group the ids together, and then check for any date occurring after the event date.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this in SQL?

EXAMPLE DATA (comma separated):

```
id,date,event,flag
1,01-Aug-14,0,0
1,02-Aug-14,0,0
2,01-Aug-14,0,0
2,02-Aug-14,1,0
3,01-Aug-14,1,0
4,01-Aug-14,0,0
5,01-Aug-14,0,0
5,02-Aug-14,1,0
5,03-Aug-14,0,1
```

Comment: What is the output you're expecting based on your example data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a subselect to count the number of events for an id prior to the date.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c0fe/2)**

```
select id,
 case 
    when (select count(1) from yourTable t2  where t2.date < t1.date and t1.id = t2.id and t2.event = 1) > 0 then 1
    else 0 
  end as flag
from
yourTable t1
```

Comment: Thank you, but this selects all columns. I only want to select the [id] and the new variable called [flag]

Comment: @user2964644 Then just edit the columns selected. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you. How can this be combined with an INSERT INTO SELECT statement to create a new table containing [id] and [flag]?

Comment: @user2964644 Just add `INSERT INTO yourOtherTableName` before the select. Also please accept this as the answer if it is the answer you are looking for.