# Separation of data rows based on a flag and timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

I want to delete/ignore/separate logs that are useful from logs that are not useful. Logs that are useful occur before or at a time that is known by a `flag`. Logs that are not useful occur after the first flagged log.

Data looks like this. Each `UID` seen at time `t`:

```
UID      t      flag      PCP
'0000'   1      0         0
'0000'   2      1         0
'0000'   3      1         0
'0000'   4      0         0
'1111'   11     1         0
'1111'   12     0         0
'1111'   13     0         0
'2222'   1      0         0
'2222'   2      0         0
'2222'   3      0         0
```

Is there a query to input a 0/1 value in PCP so I can get

```
UID      t      flag      PCP
'0000'   1      0         1
'0000'   2      1         1
'0000'   3      1         0
'0000'   4      0         0
'1111'   11     1         1
'1111'   12     0         0
'1111'   13     0         0
'2222'   1      0         0
'2222'   2      0         0
'2222'   3      0         0
```

Note: in actuality flag is \in {0,1,2} and I want PCP to reflect flag = 2. So an incremental sum() won't work.

Edit: this question is similar (different end, and I'm not good at SQl enough to know how to get the output I want from this question). [Flag dates occurring after an event within individuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119103/flag-dates-occurring-after-an-event-within-individuals)

Another edit: in sqlite you can compare strings and ints in >/= operations, and I think in SQL you cannot. My table is all in text, but comparing with integers has been going well enough, and the question above is breaking because of typing in SQL. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00448/3

Comment: final answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/86b91/1 based off accepted answer. I'm a bit unhappy with the speed (I have to do this on 10^7 logs), and will look for optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing this answer off of your SQL Fiddle you posted.  If UserID and PCP are actual TEXT datatypes, then this should work.  If they are actually varchar, then you can replace the LIKE with an = sign.

You simply need to use an exists clause to look for any record with the same userID that has a conversiontagid = 2 and check the time....

```
Update logs
Set PCP = '1'
Where exists    (   
                select 1 
                from logs sub 
                where logs.userid LIKE sub.userid 
                and sub.conversiontagid = 2
                and sub.t >= logs.t
                )
```

I made some assumptions using your SQL fiddle because it's not exactly clear based on your question above.  But userID 4 has three records that all occurred at the same time, so I assumed that they should all three have PCP set to 1.

Here is the SQL Fiddle showing the same query used in a select statement instead of an update statement.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00448/5)

Comment: Oh, man, this is beautiful, thanks. :) if possible, would you know how to get CalculatedPCP = 1 for all logs that have no ConversionTagID = 2? Sorry this was unclear! the point was to reject all logs after a serious Conversion = 2 happened, but keep those that led up to that OR led up to nothing.

Comment: mostly I don't really understand what's happening in the query, else I'd do it. thanks :) you're creating a subtable sub of all logs with the right userid? and then some equivalence happens. How do you know which `t` to pick?

Comment: So if a userID does does not have a log record where ConversionTagID = 2, you want to set CalculatedPCP = 1 for all of those records?  Change the EXISTS to a NOT EXISTS and remove the and sub.t >= logs.t.  The t column is just time (based on what you said in your post), so the original query is saying if there exists another log record for this userID and the record occurs after the one I'm correlating with AND it has a conversiontagid = 2, then set CalculatedPCP = 1.  I would recommend reading up on correlated subqueries to get a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: will do. I want to merge the two queries, both your original fiddle example AND keep logs where no conversion happened. Thanks again :) I'm going to go read up on correlated subqueries.